# android notification bring running activity back

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I've a timeractivity with a time countdown and created a notification with an icon and the remaining time.

**what I want is that the icon click in the notification area brings back the running activity without calling onCreate()**

which initialzies everything from scratch. currently with the following code the timer starts over = no good. any help is appreciated:

```
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(getBaseContext().getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(getBaseContext().getResources().getString(R.string.state_start))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        getIntent().setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, getIntent(),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        //  Notification
        mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your situation, you might also need the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP as well as Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP.

Comment: thanks, but by changing  getIntent().setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); to  getIntent().setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); it still calls onCreate()